# Overpy for Querying OSM data in Python - Railway line length at a certain date for a city

Tags: python, time-series, geometry, openstreetmap

I have been trying to extract the length of railway lines for a city using open street map (osm) data, and the overpy query language.

My city is identified by a polygon shape in a geo pandas df.

So far, I am unable to get the length of all the different tag values for railway : subway, light_rail, monorail, tram etc..

I want to be able to get the length at a specific date as well, in order to track the growth of coverage of railway infrastructure.

Finally, I also would like to get the geometries of lines directly rather than go through the step of creating a line string from nodes so that the lengths of railway lines are exact.

Thanks for your help !

Here is what I have tried so far:

This results in a calculated length only for the last tag of the list of tags I am querying.

````
> import pandas as pd
> import geopandas as gpd
> from shapely.geometry import LineString
> 
> api = overpy.Overpass()
> 
> results_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['City_Name', 'City_ID', 'Total_Length',
>                                    'Tram_Length', 'Monorail_Length', 'Gauge_Length',
>                                    'Subway_Length', 'Funicular_Length', 'Light_Rail_Length'])
> 
> 
> for idx, city_row in subset.iterrows():
> city_name = city_row['UC_NM_MN']
> city_id = city_row['ID_HDC_G0']
> city_polygon = city_row['geometry']
> 
>     #get city polygon shape as string of coordinates 
> if isinstance(city_polygon, MultiPolygon):
> for polygon in city_polygon.geoms:
> exterior_coords = polygon.exterior.coords
> all_exterior_coords.extend(exterior_coords)
> else:
> all_exterior_coords = city_polygon.exterior.coords
> coords_str = " ".join([f"{lat} {lon}" for lon, lat in all_exterior_coords])
> 
> define query: # polygon area only reporting for last tag 
> query = f"""
> [out:json][timeout:300][maxsize:"2000000000"][date:"2020-01-01T00:00:00Z"];
> define area
> 
> nwr(poly:"{coords_str}")->.searchArea;
> 
> gather results and include geometry for tram, monorail, narrow_gauge etc.. 
>     (
> way["railway"="tram"](area.searchArea);
> way["railway"="monorail"](area.searchArea);
> way["railway"="narrow_gauge"](area.searchArea);
> way["railway"="subway"](area.searchArea);
> way["railway"="funicular"](area.searchArea);
> way["railway"="light_rail"](area.searchArea);
>     );
> 
> 
> out geom;
>     """
> 
> result = api.query(query)
> 
> lengths = {'tram': 0, 'monorail': 0, 'narrow_gauge': 0,
>               'subway': 0, 'funicular': 0, 'light_rail': 0}
> 
>     #loop through each way and extract  nodes coords to create LineString
> for way in result.ways:
> nodes = [(node.lon, node.lat) for node in way.nodes]
> line_geometry = LineString(nodes)
> 
> get type of railway tag and add its length to total 
> for key in lengths.keys():
> if key.upper() in way.tags['railway']:
> lengths[key] += line_geometry.length
> 
> gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=[line_geometry for way in result.ways for line_geometry in [LineString([(node.lon, node.lat) for node in way.nodes])]], crs="EPSG:4326").to_crs(crs="EPSG:3395")
> 
> overall total length for all types combined
> overall_total_length = gdf['geometry'].length.sum()
> 
> print(f"Total length of the system in {city_name}:", overall_total_length) ```
````

Comment: Please fix the indentation.